# ANSIBLE Store a part of tasks output on a local file

Tags: logging, module, ansible

In my playbook I have two major tasks one task that change the gateway last digit for Debian machines and the second one applies to Redhat machines everything works fine but to be able to trace the machines on which the tasks were executed succesfully on a local file (kind of a log).

I tried to register the results of both tasks with a register

for Debian :

```yaml
 name: change default gateway address
      replace:
        path: /etc/network/interfaces
        regexp: '(up route add default gw [\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.254'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "Debian")
      register: debresult
```

for Redhat:

```yaml
- name: change default gateway address on Redhat
      replace:
        path: /etc/sysconfig/network-scripts/ifcfg-eth0
        regexp: '(GATEWAY=[\d]*\.[\d]*.[\d]*)\.[\d]*$'
        replace: '\1.254'
        backup: yes
      when: (ansible_facts['distribution'] == "RedHat")
      register: redresult
```

and then I added a task to log the changed hosts :

```yaml
    - name: log the changed hosts
      local_action:
        module : copy
        content: "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{debresult}}"
        content: "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{redresult}}"
        dest: /tmp/changed.txt
```

What I am trying to have is a log like this :

```
debianhostname {"msg": "", "success": true, "changed": true}
redhathostname {"msg": "", "success": true, "changed": true}
```

But the problem is that I only get the last output so how can have both entries in my file? is there a module that I can use ? I have tried the local_action with copy, set_fact but it did not work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

copy content will replace the file content with last result in your case. In the following code I used shell module and with_items to redirect to a file on localhost.

```
 - name: log the changed hosts
   shell: echo "{{ item }}" >> /tmp/changed.txt
   with_items: 
      - "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{debresult}}"
      - "{{ansible_facts.hostname}}{{redresult}}"
   delegate_to: "localhost"
```

Comment: Hello @altair66 I just so your answer I managed to do the same using lineinfile and local_action since I made up my mind to use ansible modules as much as possible and leave shell commands as last resort I'll share my answer

Comment: I just want to let you know that I tried the echo and it is working fine also and I get the same logging output thank you for taking time to read and respond.

Comment: Sure Thanks @Jinja_dude will try to answer future questions with only ansible modules and other shell and command as last resort.

Answer (score 0):

I managed to find a way to log the task details locally using as much as possible of ansible modules

```yaml
 - name: log the changed hosts
      local_action:
        module : lineinfile
        line: "{{ ansible_facts['hostname'] }} {{item}}"
        dest: /tmp/changed.txt
      with_items:
        - "{{debresult}}"
        - "{{redresult}}"
```

And @altair66 suggestion works fine also I get the same result.